# Windows search results in a tree or taxonomy form

Tags: windows, search

I want to search keyword inside files and then have results show as as tree/taxonomy not just plain one dimensional list of files.

Is there some way to setup windows search this way?

Comment: You probably need to ask Microsoft if they can do this.